# Не работает intent в меню? Android Search

Tags: java, android, activity, android-search-view

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать так , чтобы при нажатии на иконку поиска из меню, приложение переходило на новое активити.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(this,Search.class);
            startActivity(searchIntent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_logout:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

сделал это вот таким образом, но к сожалению приложение не создает новое активити просто без реакции.

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:title="@string/menu_logout"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: Убедитесь, что switch заводит вас в нужный кейс. Поставьте брейк поинт и прям построчно проверьте. И убедитесь, что а манифесте ваше второе активити описано

Comment: Проверил манифест , там изменил но не помогло.

Comment: Вам нужно создать ее просто как обычный айтем , без app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView